# How can I read my text file into an array and print that into the console to prove it's working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity and C# to retrieve text from an external text file. There are no errors at runtime; but it doesn't appear to do anything and it doesn't print to the console.
Thank you.

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("Assets/Hats Table.txt");
String itemStrings = reader.ReadLine();
while (itemStrings != null) 
{
    char[] delimiter = {'@'};
    string[] fields = itemStrings.Split(delimiter);
    itemStrings = reader.ReadLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < itemStrings.Length; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log("Primary key is " + i + ". The data is " + itemStrings[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: just create a console app and copy paste the code into the Main or some other method you call, and add some Console.WriteLines calls inside the for loop.. what's the problem.. and what's not working that you have to prove that it's not working..?

Comment: also what does the space in this name represent `"Assets/Hats Table.txt");` where are you pre-pending or declaring the initial filepath.. can you also show a snippet of what the data looks like..?

Comment: itemStrings is a string, so looping through its length will give you each character in the line.  Probably not what you want.  You're splitting the line on the `@` symbol into a variable called `fields`.  Did you mean to print that out instead?

Comment: Can you show us the contents of what's in "Assets/Hats Table.txt" (or at least, the first two lines, as that's all you're reading here)? And have you tried a `Debug.Log("Here!")` at the beginning before opening the file to ensure at least that much is executing?  I assume you're able to attach a debugger and step through line by line - what do you see happening?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code reads the first line, splits the string on '@' (fields is not used at all), reads the next line, loops through each character in itemStrings and prints each character and continues (while loop) until itemStrings is null.

I suppose what you are attempting to do is read the text file line by line, split each line by '@' and print the strings for each line.

```
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("./Assets/something.txt");
    String itemStrings = reader.ReadLine();
    char[] delimiter = {'@'};

    while (itemStrings != null) 
    {
        string[] fields = itemStrings.Split(delimiter);

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
        {
            Debug.Log("Primary key is " + i + ". The data is " + fields[i]);
        }

        itemStrings = reader.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you!! <3 Thank you so much. It's perfect! :D

Answer (score 1):

You're only reading the first two lines from the file, not the entire file.  Here's a greatly simplified version that prints out each line one at a time, which I think is what you are trying to do:

```
    string[] reader = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines( "Assets/Hats Table.txt" );
    for ( int i = 0; i < reader.Length; i++ )
    {
        Debug.Log( "Primary key is " + i + ". The data is " + reader[i]  + "\n");
    }
```